# Using Java & BoofCV to detect shapes in an image file

Tags: java, image-processing, shapes, boofcv

I've not found anything here or on google. I'm looking for a way to identify shapes (circle, square, triangle and various other shapes) from a image file. Some examples:

[image: filled circle] [image: unfilled triangle] [image: crosses][image: quadrant filled square] [image: multiple shapes] [image: multiple shapes pac]

You get the general idea. Not sure if BoofCV is the best choice here but it looks like it should be straightforward enough to use, but again I know nothing about it. I've looked at some of the examples and I though before I get in over my head (which is not hard to do some days), I thought I would ask if there is any info out there.

I'm taking a class on Knowledge Based AI solving Ravens Progressive Matrix problems and the final assignment will use strictly visual based images instead of the text files with attributes. We are not being graded on the visual since we only have a few weeks to work on this section of the project and we are encouraged to share this information. SOF has always been my go to source for information and I'm hoping someone out there might have some ideas on where to start with this...

Essentially what I want to do is detect the shapes (?? convert them into 2D geometry) and then make some assumptions about attributes such as size, fill, placement etc, create a text file with these attributes and then using that, send it through my existing code based that I wrote for my other projects to solve the problems.

Any suggestions????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways you can do it.  One way is to find the contour of the shape then fit a polygon to it or a oval. If you git a polygon to it and there are 4 sides with almost equal length then its a square.  The contour can be found with binary blobs (my recommendation for the above images) or canny edge.

http://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Example_Fit_Polygon
http://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Example_Fit_Ellipse

Comment: I finally got a chance to check out the example and I believe that is exactly what I am looking for.